# string slicing in python swith pywapi

Tags: python, slice, weather

I have developed a program in python to tell the weather.
I have used the pywapi module. I want to slice the location it provides.

Consider the following example:

```
>>> pywapi.get_location_ids('new york')
{u'JMXX0950': u'New York, 14, Jamaica', u'UKXX7149': u'New York, LIN, United         
Kingdom', u'JMXX1405': u'New York, 06, Jamaica', u'USNY0996': u'New York, NY'}
```

I want just the location id. Could anybody help me with slicing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the API returns a Python dictionary where the location ID is the key and the elaborate meaningful names are the values.

So you can just use the `keys` method to get the location IDs.

```
data = pywapi.get_location_ids('new york')
print(data.keys())
```

Comment: I would like to print the name of the city also.

Comment: Can you please show me the expected output from above?

Comment: What i mean is it should print the name of the city and the code like this:                     'New York : USNY0996 ' i.e 'Name of city: city code' for each of the values in the dictionary.

Comment: So you just want to keep the first part of the value portion? Like just `New York` from `'New York, 06, Jamaica'`?

Comment: No, i want both the name of the city and the code in an easy to read format, as i mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the answer myself with help from your above answer. Thanks!